# Errno::ENOENT on line ["346"] of C: No such file or directory -

Tags: ruby, drupal, sass, bundler, guard

I'm using Sass, Compass, Guard and Bundler. When I do `bundle exec guard` on command line in the root of the theme with the config.rb gemfile and guardfile, it gives me this output but it does not compile my sass files:

```
C:\wamp\www\fitzindustries\sites\all\themes\fitzindustries>bundle exec guard
Errno::ENOENT on line ["346"] of C: No such file or directory - C:/wamp/www/fitz
industries/sites/all/themes/fitzindustries/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e
41567cc2a7d8997/C%058%092Ruby193%092lib%092ruby%092gems%0921.9.1%092gems%092comp
ass-core-1.0.0%092stylesheets%092compass%092utilities%092general%092_hacks.scssc
20140822-1732-lofyx5.lock
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

17:30:22 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
17:30:22 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
17:30:23 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
17:30:23 - INFO - Guard is now watching at 'C:/wamp/www/fitzindustries/sites/all
/themes/fitzindustries'
```

It seems there is a problem with the .sass-cache folder. I have tried changing permissions on this folder and deleting the folder, but it does not help.
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does your config.rb file point to your actual Sass and CSS directories? What version of Sass are you using? What version Compass?

Comment: @KatieK compass 1.0.1 sass 3.4.1

# Location of the theme's resources.
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "styles/css"
sass_dir = "styles/sass"
images_dir = "images"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
javascripts_dir = "js"

all my folders are in the theme root ecept css and sass folders which are both in styles eg (root/)styles/css & (root/)styles/sass

Answer (score 1):

We had an identical problem on a Windows machine and ended up adding the following to the config.rb file, which made the issue disappear:

```
sass_options = {:cache_location => "path\to\tmp\sass-cache"}
```

We don't have a lot of Sass files to compile, so there were no speed issues associated with turning off that cache for us, but your milage may vary!